# jquery validate doesn't send form

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using Jquery validate plugin in to validate a form, everything is fine with the validation my problem is in the submitHandler function which for some reason i dont' get isn't sending the form to my mail, I checked the php and is totally fine. This is a file of what im doing more complete http://jsfiddle.net/KszmV/

Other thing that i need to do and i dont know how to do it, It is how to submit the form without loading again the page and showing a message at the end of the form

this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#contactusform1").validate({
            rules: {
                "name": {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 3
                },
                "phone":{
                    required:true,
                    digits:true
                },
               "email":{
                    required: true
                }

            },
            messages: {
                "name": {
                    required: "Please enter a name"
                },
                "phone":{
                    required: "Please provide a contact number"
                },
                "email":{
                    required: "Enter a valid email"
                }
            },
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },

            submitHandler: function (form) {    

                $.ajax({ 
                    type: 'POST', 
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    url: 'process-contact1.php', 
                    success: function () {

                    }                        

                });

                form.submit();
            }           

        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you calling both `$.ajax()` and `form.submit()`?

Comment: The [jQuery Form Plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api) is helpful for submitting the form without reloading the page.

Comment: I dint know that use the form.submit is wrong when u use $.ajax(), now if i take out the form.submit the form wont clear the fields(reset) how can i do this?? and even doing this i have tried and the data doesnt get send anyway....ty in advance

Comment: `$.ajax()` sends the form data, `form.submit()` sends it again, so you only need one of them. If you want to clear the form data after sending AJAX, you have to do that in your JavaScript, e.g. `$(form).find("input").val('');`

Comment: You should use `form.reset()` inside ajax `success` callback if you want to reset the form after successful form submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues

```
submitHandler: function (form) {    
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST', 
        data: $(form).serialize(), // $(form) is ok here
        url: 'process-contact1.php', 
        success: function () {
        }                        
    });
    form.submit();  //<-- REMOVE this
    return false; //<-- ADD this
}
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Y8cHm/**

- remove `form.submit()` since the plugin is already handling this.
- you need a `return false` within the `submitHandler` since you're doing `ajax` or you'll get a normal submit/page refresh.
- [Your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KszmV/) was missing a `</form>` tag.
- [Your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KszmV/) was linking to the plugin's [gitHub page](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/jquery.validate.js) instead of [the CDN.](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js)
- `$(form).serialize()` is perfectly acceptable as shown above in working demo.  With quotes, `$('form')` simply targets any `<form>` on the page.  Whereas `$(form)` is targeting the same form element as already passed into your `.validate()` function.  *In your demo, they both give the same result although that may not hold true for all other situations.*

Comment: ty for answer like always, i did what i said and the form does not get to the mail yet, any ideas, i have checked my php and it is fine, if u need it i can jsfiddle it success: function () {
                  form.reset();
                     $('#submitbtn').hide();
                     $('#success-line').show().fadeOut(7000, function(){
                      $('#submitbtn').show("slow");
                     });
                 }